# Set default width instead of number of columns (wordpress gallery)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, gallery

I need to build a gallery on Wordpress but I want to specify a default width instead of number of columns.

For example:

Gallery's default width - 100px (I'm just using random numbers in order to explain what I mean)

Image 1's width - 40px

Image 2's width - 50px

Image 3's width - 70px

In this scenario, Images 1 and 2 would go on the first row (cause their combined width is less than 100px), while Image 3 would end up below.

Basically, I want to write something like this:

```
 function theme_gallery_defaults( $settings ) {
     $settings['galleryDefaults']['columns'] = 5;
     return $settings;
 }
 add_filter( 'media_view_settings', 'theme_gallery_defaults' );
```

but instead of a fixed number of columns, I'd like to have a fixed width.

Is this possible?!

Comment: Your question seems inconsistent -  I'd like to have a fixed width - but - (Image 1's width - 40px) != (Image 2's width - 50px).

Comment: If you want a gallery with fixed width images, i.e. all images have the same width which is specified by you in px units you can use the filter ''gallery_style' to override the style that WordPress is applying to the gallery with your own styles.

Comment: If you want a gallery with images with their natural widths you can use the filter ''gallery_style' to override the style that WordPress is applying to the gallery with your own styles.

Comment: Essentially, WordPress uses a percentage width to achieve the fixed number of columns, e.g, columns == 5 then width = 20%, columns=3 then width = 33%. You just need to override that width css.

Comment: Hi! Honestly this is so hard for me to explain hahaha what I mean is:
let's say the whole gallery width is 1000px. So, when I upload Image 1 (width: 500px) it should fit on the first row. When I upload Image 2, if its width is larger than 500px (therefore, exceeding the total of 1000px), I need it to go to the second row. So my fixed width would be 1000px. Sorry if it's confusing!

Comment: If you fix the gallery width and it is a large width it may not work well on small screen devices - tablets and phones.

Comment: True! But I was thinking of fixing it using another unit, such as vw. My gallery is a bit different so basically on small screens I just need it to look the same, but proportionally small, you know?

Comment: Because of the way WordPress structures the images in a gallery it may be difficult to adjust the css to show the natural width of an image. Fixed width images are very easy but natural width images would require some tricky css. I have never done it but I think it can be done. You can use the filter 'gallery_style' to do this.

Comment: I think you should try an existing plugin that has this kind of functionality. The effort to do this and get a pretty result when the images don't have the same height is probably non-trivial and has probably been solved by someone before who has expended a lot of time and effort fine tuning it to be pretty.

Comment: I spent some time thinking about what you want to do. The only css only solution I could think of would result in an ugly gallery with a very uneven right margins on the rightmost images. In order to do better I think you will need to restructure the HTML document tree of the gallery and use JavaScript to dynamically adjust the css of the HTML elements in that tree. If you have not done this before I think the effort to do this and get a really pretty result - no uneven margins, everything nicely aligned - is days or weeks. This is a common problem which has been solved before.

Comment: The effort to finely tune the position, alignment and size of the images is very time consuming. I think unless you are doing this for the experience you will be better off using a plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll look for a plugin. Thank you so much for your help though!